# What is the analogue of the RichFaces' "rich:findComponent" function in PrimeFaces?

Tags: primefaces, richfaces

I'm new in project migration from RichFaces to PrimeFaces and for now dont have strong understanding of it. There's code sample to migrate from RichFaces:

```
<c:set var="formName" value="#{jsfUtils.getComponentFormName(rich:findComponent(id.concat('modalCheckBoxPanel')))}" />
```

So here I dont know how to replace "rich:findComponent" function to receive UIComponent instance on PrimeFaces manner. Is there any analogues of it or it has another way to do so in PrimeFaces? Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: I don't know what `rich:findComponent` does, is it the same as http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resolveComponent ?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Functions.html#sect-Component_Reference-Functions-findComponent

Comment: What does `id.concat('modalCheckBoxPanel'))` return in the context of a full real example

Comment: You can use PF for similar functionality in Primefaces, but instead of id it consume widgetVar. Following link [Alternative of richfaces components in primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951953/alternative-of-richfaces-components-in-primefaces/46989556#46989556) can be usefull during migration.