# Emulate bypassUpdates when migrate from RichFaces to PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, richfaces, omnifaces

What's the best way to emulate the `bypassUpdates` property of `a4j:support`? This property skip JSF phase 4 and 5, no matter if validation success or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that `immediate="true"` in PF ?  See: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/commandbutton?id=commandbutton

Comment: Nop, immediate is a different behavior.

Comment: Maybe ask this guy he seems to be the expert: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46989556/502366